# Google Maps v3 autocomplete search only works in IE

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm having a minor problem with an autocomplete search box. My application seems to work fine in IE, but when I try it in Firefox or Chrome, the search box doesn't function.

Unfortunately I'm pretty much of a newbie at mashups and javascript but I've managed to piece something together based on other examples from various sources. So forgive me if it's not the most elegant thing in the world! ;) It's a bit of a hodgepodge that I've been building in stages. I'm nervous about trying to streamline it much because I'm under a time constraint as it's a class project and don't want to mess up what already works. No doubt I have a lot to learn yet and I welcome suggestions.  I just may not be able to apply them before I have to turn it in.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with the autocomplete? Also, I noticed that the Map/Satellite view buttons no longer worked after I built in the search functionality. My solution to that was to disable/hide the buttons! If anyone has any hints on that too, let me know.

Here's where the app is located: http://webpages.charter.net/nymbli/displays.htm

For some reason, I'm not able to get my code to post here but please feel free to view the source code for the page.

Thanks in advance,

Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `<script type="text/javascript">` tag. Remove that and look at the source in Firefox. The HTML errors are highlighted. In general, **never use IE for development**. Use a real browser instead. ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions, Marcelo. I appreciate your help. I've tried removing the extra tags and viewed the source in Firefox. I don't see any errors highlighted in red anymore now. But I'm still finding that while everything works in IE, the search box still doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @user1888218 I just looked at your source again. You **still** have extra <script> tags.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks again for your reply. Sorry, but I really am new to this. So I'm not seeing the extra <script> tags you're referring to. I did a lot of playing around with the previous code,  removing the ones I thought I could do without and changing the order. It seems like everything I left in there, I still need otherwise the whole thing blows up. I've looked at several other examples and can't make the connection. Could you tell me again exactly what I need to remove?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Anne K.,  immediately after the line that links lightbox.css, in the next line, there's an extra <script> tag. Look at the source in Firefox. It is not highlighted red, but notice that the highlight color changes, indicating a problem. If you can't see it use an HTML validator here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks again for your help and also the garbage cleanup tips.  I'm sure I'll use the validator.w3.org site often going forward. I've removed the obsolete <script language="JavaScript"> line and the Validator isn't finding any other errors. Unfortunately the search box functionality still isn't working in Firefox.  My search box code is almost an exact copy of the following example (which works fine in FF!): https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox . So I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @Anne K.,Now you're loading the API twice, (in one of them the **experimental** version), and there is no attempt in your code to create an autocomplete object. Aside from that, if you don't bother to up-vote useful answers then this is a waste of time. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, I was glad to see your response yesterday and tried to up-vote your original answer right then, but the error message said I didn't have enough reputation points to do so (this is my first post here). As I mentioned, I'm just starting out with javascript and wasn't able to find my issue addressed in any of the other searches I did. But apparently this isn't the place to go if you're a total newbie like me. I can appreciate that. But trust me, being a newbie is just as frustrating to me as your dealing with my newbieness is.  So...sorry back atcha. I'm off. Thanks again, FWIW.

Comment: @Anne K. No worries. We've all been newbies at some time. The thing with this site is that extended discussions in the comments are not useful to the community. Question with external code...comment...correction to the external code...new problem...start all over... is not a useful routine, especially because the external code no longer reflects the original question so future readers will not be able to make much sense of it. By the way, accepting answers does not require any minimum reputation. ;-)